# Separar y Extraer elementos de una cadena con numeros y letras!

Tags: php

Como puedo extraer ciertos elementos de una cadena?
ejemplo:

```
 $cadena="11d08mo2016y";
```

de la cual necesito extraer unicamente los numeros dados de x cadena por separado quedando asi!

```
$cadena[0]=11
$cadena[1]=08
$cadena[2]=2016
```

estaba probando con la funcion explode,pero al parecer no destruye la cadena en partes, de antemano gracias!

```
 $day= explode("d",$cadena);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

explode separa por el delimitador que tu le des, en este caso `"d"`, por lo que te traerá 2 cadenas el resultado `[11, 08mo2016y]` al segundo resultado tendrías que hacer otro explode con el segundo elemento y así sucesivamente, puedes hacerlo mediante recursividad o iteración

```
function explodeFecha($dato) {
   $delimitadores = ['d', 'mo', 'y'];
   $arreglo = [];
   foreach($delimitadores as $delimiter) {
      $explodeDato = explode($delimiter, $dato);
      $arreglo[] = $explodeDato[0];
      $dato = isset($explodeDato[1])? $explodeDato[1] : NULL;
      //si usas php 7 o sueperior puedes usar para simplificar
      //$dato = $explodeDato[1] ?? NULL;
   }
   return $arreglo;
}

print_r(explodeFecha('11d08mo2016y'));
```

Lo recomendable también sería que validaras que el formato es el deseado para que no salten errores

Answer (score 5):

Lo primero es eliminar las letras mientras se convierte al mismo tiempo el `string` en un `array`, eso lo haces por medio de la siguiente función:

```
$cadena="11d08mo2016y";
$array = preg_split('/[^0-9]+/i', $cadena);
```

Luego para asegurarnos que no queden espacios en blanco hacemos un filtro al `array` formando uno nuevo sin esos espacios:

```
$array_sin_espacios = array_filter($array, function($dato){
    if($dato == ''){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});

var_dump($array_sin_espacios);
```

Comment: en la regex hace falta poner un cuantificador tal que `[^0-9]+` o no hace falta?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @lois6b lo pasé por alto ya edité la respuesta, vos sos el duro en RegExp :D

Comment: No lo sabia fijo, solo preguntaba. me daba pereza hacer un fiddle de php: he comprobado que no afecta https://www.ideone.com/NH2vfQ

Comment: Veo que al colocar el + en caso de que haya una letra al final la deja como un espacio entonces de todas formas es necesario hacer el filtro.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la funcioan `preg_split` y aplicar una expresión regular, algo así:

```
$cadena="11d08mo2016y";
$r = preg_split("/[A-Za-z]+/", $cadena);
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un for, algo así:

```
$cadena="11d08mo2016y";      
$array = [];
$count = 0;
$valor = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($cadena);$i++)
{
   if (is_numeric($cadena[$i]))
   {
      $count++;
      $valor = $valor.$cadena[$i];
   }
else
{
  if($count>0)
  {
     array_push($array, $valor);
     $valor = '';
     $count=0;
  }
}
```